# Database ignoring rows with same value in column - Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am populating a RecyclerView with a table that has two columns it's basically a dictionary and when ever I call the method to start populating something unusual happens, the code ignores the rows with the same values in the first column "col1" and just get the last one and moves to the next and so on

JAVA

```
public void fetchData()
{
    db =new DataBaseHelper(getContext());
    try {

        db.createDataBase();
        db.openDataBase();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    namelist=new LinkedHashMap<>();
    int ii;
    SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sd.query("dictionary_lib" ,null, null, null, null, null, null);
    ii=cursor.getColumnIndex("English_lib");
    eng_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    nor_list= new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        namelist.put(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("German_lib")));
    }
    Iterator entries = namelist.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        eng_list.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getKey()));
        german_list.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getValue()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eng_list.size(); i++) {
        data.add(new DictObjectModel(eng_list.get(i), german_list.get(i)));
    }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

EXAMPLE OF THE DATABASE

here the recyclerview will ignore the first two rows of alpha and prints the third one and move to the next

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually most likely because you are putting the values in a  [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which implements the map interface which states

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

You are retrieving duplicate keys here:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    namelist.put(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("German_lib")));
}
```

So the first two example values are replaced in the map as the key `"alpha"` is duplicated.

To verify this you could just print out or step over the values within the loop above.

One way to resolve this would be to create your own java object:

```
public class Example
{
    public String col1; // but appropriate names
    public String col2; 

    // Add constructors or getters and setting if you want private members
}
```

then use an Arraylist and in your loop

```
List<Example> rows = new ArrayList<>;
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    Example e = new Example();
    e.col1 = cursor.getString(ii);
    e.col2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("German_lib"))
    rows.add(e)
}
```

**EDIT**

You are creating multiple loops just to get to the same result. So you could just within your cursor loop just put

```
data.add(new DictObjectModel(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("German_lib")));
```

Comment: Yes, I actually noticed that, but  can't think of a way to fix it, if can please guide me through

Comment: See my edit to use your own object and just use a list - the advantage of this is that if you later add a 3rd column it is easier refactor.

Comment: and what are the changes that I should apply to `Iterator entries = namelist.entrySet().iterator();` after following your solution ?

Comment: Didn't see that, you don't even need that object really. You are creating multiple loops, just to get to the same result really. You could just within your cursor loop just put `data.add(new DictObjectModel(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getColumnIndex("German_lib")));`

Comment: so you're basically saying that I don't need all of this : `Iterator entries = namelist.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        eng_list.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getKey()));
        german_list.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getValue()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eng_list.size(); i++) {
        data.add(new DictObjectModel(eng_list.get(i), german_list.get(i)));
    }`  ??

Comment: Yes, The iterator got the values from the map to put them into the lists and then the for loop got them from the list to put them into `data` - so why move them around so much when the map and list are only used in this method.

Comment: it is working, just some glitches like the list goes completely blank maybe because I put the `data.add()` inside the while, I fuguring out a solution now

Comment: Not sure I can help with that one - if you can't solve it try creating another question. Also don't forget to `close()` your `Cursor` once you are done with it.